# float left not working on sass

Tags: reactjs, sass

I am working on a project where I am displaying a list of items. I used float: left to make title to appear next to icon but the problem is all the elements next to the first element are appearing on the same line(kind of).

```css
.icon
  width: 150px
  float: left
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Here is the [link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BXVEj) to the project:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this after on the content part

```
<div style={{clear: 'both'}}>{val.overview}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use floats, remember to clear them after. For example clean way to do it could be with pseudo element on `.box`:

```css
.box
  width: 600px
  &:after
    content: ''
    clear: both
    display: block
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZRgjzr?editors=0110